# How should I assign Postgres date type to a variable

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm inserting expiration dates into Postgres in a column which has this schema:
`exp  DATE  NOT NULL`

The way I'm creating these dates in Golang is with the "time" library that uses a `Time` data type (Not sure if it's underlying type is a string, the go docs didn't really specify [see here](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time)).

Here's how I'm doing the insertion with the [pgx](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4?tab=doc) library

```golang
expirationDate := time.Unix(expiresAt, 0)
sql := `
  insert into items 
  (sub, uuid, exp) 
  VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
`
_, err := connection.Exec(
  context.Background(),
  sql,
  subject,
  id,
  expirationDate,
)
```

Somewhere else in my code `expiresAt` is made like this:

```golang
days := 1 * 24 * time.Hour
expirationTime := time.Now().Add(days)
expirationTime.Unix() // this is what's being passed in my function (expiresAt int64) that does the DB insertion
```

The problem is trying to get that date back out of Postgres.
When I look at it in pgAdmin I see it's being stored as yyyy-mm-dd so I assumed maybe I could assign it to a string variable so I tried this:

```golang
type RevokedRefreshToken struct {
  OldUUID           string
  OldExpirationDate string
}
var revokedRefreshToken RevokedRefreshToken
err := connection.QueryRow(context.Background(), "select uuid, exp from items where sub = $1", subject).
Scan(&revokedRefreshToken.OldUUID, &revokedRefreshToken.OldExpirationDate)
```

I also tried:
- int64 type
- Time  type
- not passing it using its memory address (without the & in Scan())

I still can't figure out the data type I'm suppose to assign this DB value to.
Here is the error I'm getting that I think is from pgx:
`can't scan into dest[1]: unable to assign to *string`

What data type do I need to be using to assign this DB value of PostgreSQL [date type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I remember correctly `pgx` maps `DATE` to `time.Time`. To scan you either need a pointer to the pointer or use `pgx`'s `pgtype.Date` datatype (I am used to these so I always use them):

```golang
var dt pgtype.Date
err := conn.QueryRow("select exp from items where sub = $1", 1).Scan(&dt)
```

`pgtype.Date` has then field called `Time` which is of type `time.Time` so you should be able to work with it normally. See [documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/jackc/pgtype#Date).